# how to set background of activity by user choice in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativer);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgorange);
```

I want the `bgorange` to get retrieved from a spinner. So `bgorange` is a static value for now.

Comment: Means you want to change the bgcolor from the spinner selection right ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, for getting a resource programmatically you can use:

```
public static final Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int id) {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id);
}
```

So, in your exmaple you can use it like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativer);
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(context, YourSpinner.getYourResBackground());
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)
```

Note that you need the latest support lib in your build.grade

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:xxxxxx
```